# How to find out where the table is stored?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the name of a table and i want to find out in what file(s) oracle stores it.
Is there a way to do it?

Thanks ahead and sorry for my poor english!

Comment: The user is asking whether it's possible to find out where Oracle is storing a database object based on the name of the object.  I don't know the answer, but that's what the question is.  While the question might be clearer if the user spoke better English, it wouldn't be improved by adding more text.

Comment: To those who vote dto close this as NARQ: The question should be perfectly intelligible to anybody who understands the Oracle database.  If you don't understand the Oracle RDBMS you have no business voting on questions so tagged.

Comment: @APC: I voted to close as NARQ because it's too vague. Is the OP asking where on disk the table stored? Which tablespace the table is stored in? Which schema the table is located within? The question is too broad as written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle holds its tables on *logical* data stores called tablespaces.  Tablespaces abstract the actual OS location of the tables' data.

You can find the tablespace by querying user_tables if you own the object.

```
select TABLE_NAME,TABLESPACE_NAME 
from USER_TABLES 
where TABLE_NAME='<your table name>';
```

Or all_tables if you do not own it but do have access to it.

```
select OWNER,TABLE_NAME,TABLESPACE_NAME 
from ALL_TABLES 
where OWNER='<owner of the table>' 
and TABLE_NAME='<your table name>';
```

A tablespace has one or more datafiles, which are actual allocations of disk storage.  Storage is assigned as extents, which represent chunks of a data file i.e. disk space.  If a tablespace has several datafiles, a table can be assigned extents from any of those files.

If you want to find what file the extents are in you will need access to dba_extents and dba_data_files.  The file_name is the absolute OS path of the datafile.

```
select F.FILE_NAME, E.OWNER, E.SEGMENT_NAME,E.SEGMENT_TYPE
from dba_extents E 
     join dba_data_files F 
          on E.FILE_ID = F.FILE_ID
where E.OWNER='<owner of the table>' 
and E.SEGMENT_NAME='<your table name>';
```

Make sure to replace ' and  with the actual owner and table name.